# Call MySQL procedure with OUT parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, ado.net, out-parameters

I want to get the id of the last inserted row from mysql, but i get somekind of Exception unhandled. The visual studio gives me this error :

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'OUT or INOUT argument 9 for routine test.pr_VendegFelvetele is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger'.
```

mysql code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_VendegFelvetele(
    IN uvezNev VARCHAR(75), 
    IN ukerNev VARCHAR(75), 
    IN uemail VARCHAR(255), 
    IN utel INT(15), 
    IN ucim VARCHAR(75), 
    IN uiranyito INT(5), 
    IN uvaros VARCHAR(55), 
    IN uorszag VARCHAR(45),
    OUT uvendegID INT(11)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `vendeg`(`vezNev`, `kerNev`, `email`, `tel`, `cim`, `iranyito`, `varos`, `orszag`) 
VALUES (uvezNev, ukerNev, uemail, utel, ucim, uiranyito, uvaros, uorszag);
SET uvendegID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

By the way mysql procedure works perfectly.

c# code:

```
String query = "CALL pr_VendegFelvetele(@uvezNev, @ukerNev, @uemail, @utel, @ucim, @uiranyito, @uvaros, @uorszag, @uvendegID);";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, Con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uvezNev", uvezNev);
                cmd.Parameters["@uvezNev"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ukerNev", ukerNev);
                cmd.Parameters["@ukerNev"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uemail", uemail);
                cmd.Parameters["@uemail"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@utel", utel);
                cmd.Parameters["@utel"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ucim", ucim);
                cmd.Parameters["@ucim"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uiranyito", uiranyito);
                cmd.Parameters["@uiranyito"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uvaros", uvaros);
                cmd.Parameters["@uvaros"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uorszag", uorszag);
                cmd.Parameters["@uorszag"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uvendegID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                cmd.Parameters["@uvendegID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                Con.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show(cmd.Parameters["@uvendegID"].Value.ToString());
```

I get it on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-stored-using.html ,   https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36484/Working-C-code-for-MySql-Stored-Procedures-IN-OUT - see CommandType usage.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to add these lines, and now works like a charm.
```
cmd.CommandText = "pr_VendegFelvetele";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: Cool, consider adding it as an answer - including links and such! It’s okay to answer your own questions (especially if nobody else steps up) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added these lines and now it works.

```
cmd.CommandText = "pr_VendegFelvetele";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

This link helped:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-stored-using.html

Comment: Maybe you can mark your solution as the answer, so that can help others find the solution quickly.